# how to configure tomcat to send the logs in JSON format to configure in logstash

Tags: tomcat7

To setup loggly alerts in logStash we need to configure tomcat server to return logs in JSON format.

The logs shipped to loggly are presently not in expected format (JSON). They are in .out and .log formats currently.
we need to analyze on writing the logs in JSON format in tomcat server.